# Bash function not called when checking for root perms

Tags: bash, root, debian-based

I want to make a bash script which checks if specified packages are installed. Doing this normally requires root permissions.

I expected the whole code to work, but when calling `check_requirements` it does not work.
It doesn't print any message.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This function installs the specified dependencies when called
install_requirements () {
    echo "$BCyan Downloading required packages... $Color_Off"
    apt-get install -y ${pkgs[@]}
    
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$Green Requirements are installed."
    else
        echo "$BRed Error encountered while downloading requirements."
    fi
    echo "$Blue Cleaning apt leftovers... $Color_Off" && apt-get autoclean && apt-get autoremove
}

# This function check if specified dependencies (aka packages) are installed. If not, install
check_requirements () {
    pkgs=( "zip" "unzip" "wget" "curl" "default-jdk" "jq" )
    ## Run the run_install function if sany of the libraries are missing
    dpkg -s "${pkgs[@]}" >/dev/null 2>&1 || install_requirements
}

root_check () {
    if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ];then 
        sudo "$0" "$@"
        if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then 
            check_requirements
        else 
            echo "$Red Couldn't check for updates $Color_Off"
        fi
    fi
}

root_check
```

I am stuck for very long time here. Can you help me find an answer to my dilemma?

Comment: Have you tried running your script with `bash -x ...` to trace every line? I think that `dpkg` invocation is returning something that makes the `||` not trigger.

Comment: Also, the script shouldn't use `sudo` internally; not everyone uses `sudo` to escalate privileges. Instead make the script just inform it should be run as root and exit.

Comment: Third – why bother checking whether the packages exist? You can just `apt-get install -y --no-upgrade`; it won't do anything if it doesn't need to. Fourth – an installer script shouldn't call autoclean and autoremove.

Comment: Hi @AKX ! I didn't know about ```bash -x``` option. I obtained this while running the script with that option ```+ root_check
+ '[' 1000 -ne 0 ']'
+ sudo request_sudo.sh
sudo: request_sudo.sh: command not found
+ '[' 1 -eq 0 ']'
+ echo ' Couldn'\''t check for updates '
 Couldn't check for updates 
```

Comment: But I need to make an universal bash script for all terminals wich atleast prompts the user to enter a password for getting root permissions

Comment: The `set -x` output seems to reveal the `sudo` invocation is wrong; it should probably be `sudo ./request_sudo.sh` or `sudo bash request_sudo.sh` ...

Comment: You say "universal bash script" yet you assume the OS is Debian-based enough to have dpkg and apt-get, though :-)

Comment: Ok.. You got me. :3  Yes its for Debian-based distros :D

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) to your question (no comment).

Comment: And how can I do that?

Comment: By the way I still don't understand how to check if the specified dependencies exist in the system ;-;